# Number Theory: Class Groups

Tags: number-theory, ideals

I have the following question regarding class groups.

> > Show that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ is of class number 1.

From what I understand, the Minkowski bound says, for a number field $K$, that any ideal class contains an integral ideal with norm bounded above by 
\begin{equation}
\frac{n!}{n^n}  \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^{r_2}\sqrt{|\text{disc}(K)|} 
\end{equation}
In this particular example: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2!}{2^2}  \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^{1}\sqrt{19}&=& \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{19}<3 
\end{eqnarray}
Thus it is suffice to check how (2) and (3) split K.

This is where I am stuck. I was thinking of going about it using quadratic reciprocity to see how 2 and 3 split into $K$. I get split and inert respectively. Because $2$ split in $K$, I was to check and see if there were any integer solution for

\begin{eqnarray}
N\left(a+b\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}\right)\right) & = & a^2+ab+5b^2=\pm2
\end{eqnarray}

Am I on the right track? If so, how do I proceed? If not, where did I go wrong and how do I properly approach this?

Thank you for your time and thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are on the right track. You can evaluate the Jacobi symbol (or Kronecker symbol) to determine the factorisation of the ideals $(2)$ and $(3)$, see here: [How to factor ideals in a quadratic number field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043480/how-to-factor-ideals-in-a-quadratic-number-field/1043738#1043738). Then you can proceed in the usual way, like here:
[Showing that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{17})$ has class number 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382188/showing-that-mathbb-q-sqrt17-has-class-number-1).

There is another way to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ has class number one, namely the analytic class number formula. In your case the class number is equal to
$$
h=\frac{\sqrt{\mid d_k\mid}}{2\pi}L(1,\chi),
$$
with the $L$-series attached to a corresponding Dirichlet character, and $d_K=-19$. It is easy to see that this gives $h=1$, because $L(1,\chi)\sim 1.44146156829133589$.