# Notation of $(2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})$ and its Norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am lacking some really basic algebra knowledge.

Can somebody help me with the following notation in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$?

$$ (2)=(2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})(2, \frac{1 - \sqrt{d}}{2})  $$

Does it mean $$(2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})(2, \frac{1 - \sqrt{d}}{2}) = (2 + \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})(2 + \frac{1 - \sqrt{d}}{2}) \\
= 4 + (\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})( \frac{1 - \sqrt{d}}{2}) ~ ??$$

And how do I calculate the Norm of $(2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})$?

$$ N\left((2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})\right) = N\left((2 + \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})\right)  = ? $$

Comment: The ideal generated by those elements and the norm of this ideal? Does this make sense in the context of your problem?

Comment: $(2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2})$ probably denotes the ideal generated by $2$ and $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$.

Comment: It is from here (the last comment) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382188/showing-that-mathbb-q-sqrt17-has-class-number-1. I am following an algebraic number theory course and I do not know lots about algebra, so I am struggling with the notations and I do not find it explained, since it is so trivial

Comment: Then that's what @jjagmath and I suggested

Comment: I upvoted the question because of the first line "I am lacking some really basic algebra knowledge".

Comment: That the ideal product $\,(2,w)(2,\bar w) = (2)$ follows from an [ideal form of the Four Number Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4350564/242), namely $\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\!8}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{2\mid w\bar w}=(1\!-\!d)/4\,$ thus 
$$(2,w)(2,\bar w) = (2)(2,\color{#0a0}{w,\bar w},\color{#c00}{w\bar w/2})= (2)\ \ {\rm by}\ \   \,\color{#0a0}{w+\bar w} = 1\qquad$$

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4340435/242)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very helpful!